# How to update ssl on Nginx?

Tags: security, ssl, nginx

I am running nginx 1.10.1. When I run the command nginx -V, the version of openssl appears.

```
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Now when I run Openssl version I get

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 1.0.1t
```

I want to have nginx run with the most current version of openssl. Now I've looked around and I was told if it was statically linked then I would have to recompile as opposed to dynamically link. How do I know I have a statically linked version? Also what are the steps to ensure that I recompile to the correct version of openssl. Should I worry about other system dependencies when applying the patch?

I have gone through the routine of using apt-update/upgrade and individually installing package with no luck of having a proper version of openssl running.

Other information

```
Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty
Nginx 1.10.1
```

Comment: Did you install Nginx via apt-get?

Comment: Yes I did use apt-get install Nginx. I hope that does not complicate things.